# JUnit handling of RuntimeException (specifically)

Tags: java, junit, runtimeexception, checked-exceptions

I tend to throw as many checked `Exceptions` up as possible: it declutters the code (and I regard checked `Exceptions` as a dubious aspect of Java). I tend to use them when "refining" code.. i.e. when it makes sense for the particular context.

This approach gets slightly complicated when overriding superclass/interface methods which don't throw the requisite `Exception`, and therefore I tend to do this:

```
@Override
public void close() {
    try {
        _close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

where `_close` is a private method which does all the business.

The problem when it comes to JUnit, if you actually want to test something where an exception is thrown by `_close()` is that the resulting `RuntimeException` seems to be handled by JUnit in an "unconditional" way: it seems always to stop the test with a failure message... even if you actually catch and deal with it in a `try .. catch`!

There is a sort of "workaround" for this which I've found (the CUT class closes all its `closeableComponents` when it is closed):

```
@Test (expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void errorFlagShouldBeSetIfAnyCloseablesThrowExceptionWhenCUTCloses() throws Exception {
    Closeable spyCloseable = spy( new Closeable(){
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException( "dummy" );
        }});
    spyCUT.addCloseableComponent( spyCloseable );
    Exception blob = null;
    try{
        spyCUT.close();
    }catch( Exception e ){
        blob = e;
    }
    assertThat( spyCUT.getErrorFlag() ).isTrue();
    if( blob != null ){
        throw blob;
    }
```

I.e. if you don't have this `expected` setting you always get a test failure (because of the `RuntimeException` "ignoring" the `try .. catch`).  But in order to satisfy the `expected` you then have to rethrow the `RuntimeException` at the end of the test...

... is there any way of varying JUnit's handling of `RuntimeExceptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must be wrong in your setup. JUnit does **not** have any such special handling for runtime exceptions.

I put together this MCVE; and it **passes**.

```
static class CUT {
    void close(Closeable _close) {
        try {
            _close.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Closeable spyCloseable = Mockito.spy(new Closeable() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("dummy");
        }
    });
    Exception blob = null;
    try {
        new CUT().close(spyCloseable);
        fail("should have thrown");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        blob = e;
    }
    assertThat(blob.getMessage(), is("java.io.IOException: dummy"));
}
```

It is not exactly what you have up there; but "close enough" in my mind.

Long story short: your answer is coming from some other place. I suggest: do the same as I did: create a *true* mcve; and work your way from there!

Comment: Thanks very much.  I ran your test and it's exactly as you say.  Even if I just throw a new RuntimeException in the try .. catch in the test this exception is indeed caught by the catch. All very puzzling. This was done as a "Run as JUnit Test" in Eclipse. With my "real" project I am using gradle and running tests using the Eclipse STS Gradle plug-in.  I'm also using AssertJ rather than Hamcrest... will have to "work my way" to the cause, as you say.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback/quick accept! Yes; I guess you have to go for step-by-step careful debugging now; as I dont see anything in that list you just gave that would explain what you are seeing. And for the record: I only ran this test within eclipse and the built-in "run as Junit"

Comment: @mike rodent
I ran across similar issue. I am throwing IllegalStateException and If I use, catch (Exception e) then it works however if I explicitly catch it by catch (IllegalStateException e) then junit fails the test. Any ideas on this?

Comment: btw, i just figured out MCVE - Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.